# VIM ctrlp.vim plugin: how to rescan files?

Tags: vim, plugins

I have come across the awesome [ctrlp.vim plugin](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim). It is a good alternative to the [Command-T plugin](https://wincent.com/products/command-t) which I have used before. What I did not like about Command-T is that it would take about 20-30 seconds to rescan files when it is invoked for the first time after starting vim.

CtrlP works a lot faster but it does not seem to automatically rescan for newly created files. How should I trigger a rescan manually?

Thanks!

Comment: This is answered very clearly in the documentation.

Answer (score 300, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim/blob/master/doc/ctrlp.txt):

```
<F5>
  - Refresh the match window and purge the cache for the current directory.
  - Remove deleted files from MRU list.
```

This assumes you're in ctrl-p mode already. Note that you can hit F5 in the middle of a query, i.e., you can type a few characters, find it's not matching a recently updated file, and hit F5 to refresh right then. It will automatically show you the match if the file was just added to the ctrl-p cache.

Comment: Note that this must be done while in CTRL-P mode. So, 1. `ctrl-p` 2. `F5`

Comment: Almost works for me, I see it updating but it doesn't find newly added files

Comment: @xer0x Make sure that you are in the correct CWD. Had the same issue while using NERDTree.

Comment: Just to add, you can't search for your own file while you currently editing it.

Answer (score 67):

As [Jeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8663886/1523238) says you can press <kbd>F5</kbd> but if that doesn't work you can always run `:CtrlPClearCache` which is what <kbd>F5</kbd> is supposed to run.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim/blob/master/doc/ctrlp.txt#L807)

> :CtrlPClearCache
> Flush the cache for the current working directory. The same as pressing `<F5>`
> inside CtrlP.
> To enable or disable caching, use the |g:ctrlp_use_caching| option.

Comment: I have GNU screen windows mapped to my Fn keys so this is perfect - thanks!

Answer (score 11):

I added this to .vimrc which turns off ctrlp caching

`g:ctrlp_use_caching = 0`

Comment: This is probably the best and most accurate answer to the original question. Especially if you are on a computer (I'm looking at you Apple..) where the function row needs an alternate modifier key to access.

Comment: i like this answer, even with out cache, ctrp is fast enough already, can use Ag to boost up the speed

Answer (score 6):

If you want, you can automatically bust the cache when a save happens, so it will be forced to refresh on next use.

[Put this in your vimrc](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim/issues/305#issuecomment-9802791) (credit [docwhat](https://github.com/docwhat)):

```
" CtrlP auto cache clearing.
" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
function! SetupCtrlP()
  if exists("g:loaded_ctrlp") && g:loaded_ctrlp
    augroup CtrlPExtension
      autocmd!
      autocmd FocusGained  * CtrlPClearCache
      autocmd BufWritePost * CtrlPClearCache
    augroup END
  endif
endfunction
if has("autocmd")
  autocmd VimEnter * :call SetupCtrlP()
endif
```

Unfortunately there's no way to automatically keep the cache fresh in the background.

Comment: on save seems kind of expensive. is there a possible trigger for creating a new file?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a old question, but it's so simple that I have to comment.
Put this in your .vimrc

```
:nnoremap <c-p> :CtrlPClearCache<bar>CtrlP<cr>
```

This will refresh the cache and then call CtrlP. No more missing files.

Comment: Why not just disable caching with `g:ctrlp_use_caching`?